# Build vue.js survey with click highlighting

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I try to create a survey using **vue.js**, which is great. In each section the user is able to select an answer by clicking the `div.box`. After a click event I want to things to happen:

1. Assign `data-value=""` of clicked box to the `data:` layer of my app as selected answer
2. Mark the clicked `div.box` by adding `.choosen`, while the same class should be removed of all other boxes in the same section.

I got my HTML markup like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box-holder">
    <div class="box" data-value="lorem">Dogs</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box-holder">
    <div class="box" data-value="aperiam">Birds</div>
  </div> 
  ... and some more ...
</div>
```

In jQuery I could simply create a `$('.box')` selector and use `.parent()` with `removeClass()` and `addClass()`. How can I achieve the same in vuejs?

[**JS FIDDLE DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/42090/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
new Vue({
  el: ".wrapper",
  data: {
    list: [
      {
        id: 'lorem',
        text: 'Dogs'
      },
      {
        id: 'aperiam',
        text: 'Birds'
      },
      {
        id: 'aperiam2',
        text: 'Birds2'
      },
      {
        id: 'aperiam3',
        text: 'Birds3'
      }
    ],
    choosen: 'lorem'
  },
  methods: {
    onClick: function(id) {
      this.choosen = id;
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.choosen{
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div 
     class="box-holder"
     v-for="item in list" 
     :class="{ 'choosen': choosen === item.id }"
     >
    <div class="box" @click="onClick(item.id)">{{ item.text }}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey Mixa, thanks for this great and code-less suggestion. Is there a way to separate multiple sections, so for example favorite pet and favorite sport, so that it does not influence each other?

Comment: Use components I added an example

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a click handler to your element, and a conditional class binding. For example:

```
<div class="box" data-value="lorem" 
  v-on:click="favoritePet = 'dogs' "
  v-bind:class="{ choosen: favoritePet == 'dogs' }"
>Dogs</div>
```

Docs on binding classes here : https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax
And event handling here : https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html

Comment: Is there a solution in which I do not have to edit each box? Like creating a component and just passing parameters that change?

Comment: Yes there is https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html

You can create a component based on your box element, and pass and animal type to it as a prop

Answer (score 0):

Use component

```js
Vue.component('question', {
  template: '#question',
  data: function() {
    return {
      choosen: undefined
    }
  },
  props: ['data'],
  methods: {
    onClick: function(choosen) {
      this.choosen = choosen;
      this.$emit('set-question', this.choosen, this.data.id)
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    question: {},
    question1: {
      id: 'question1',
      list: [
        {
          id: 'lorem',
          text: 'Dogs'
        },
        {
          id: 'aperiam',
          text: 'Birds'
        },
        {
          id: 'aperiam2',
          text: 'Birds2'
        },
        {
          id: 'aperiam3',
          text: 'Birds3'
        }
      ],
      title: 'Your favorite pet?'
    },
    question2: {
      id: 'question2',
      list: [
        {
          id: 'lorem',
          text: 'Dogs'
        },
        {
          id: 'aperiam',
          text: 'Birds'
        },
        {
          id: 'aperiam2',
          text: 'Birds2'
        },
        {
          id: 'aperiam3',
          text: 'Birds3'
        }
      ],
      title: 'Your favorite sport?'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setQuestion: function(choosen, id) {
      this.question[id] = choosen;
      console.log(this.question);
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.choosen{
  color: red
}
#app{
  padding-bottom: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <question :data="question1" @set-question="setQuestion"></question>
  <question :data="question2" @set-question="setQuestion"></question>
</div>

<template id="question">
  <div>
    <h1>{{data.title}}</h1>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div 
           class="box-holder"
           v-for="item in data.list" 
           :class="{ 'choosen': choosen === item.id }"
           >
        <div class="box" @click="onClick(item.id)">{{ item.text }}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```